# entityManager.find() is returning unexpected object

Tags: jpa, spring-boot

I have a model named User and I am trying to fetch values of User using entityManager.find();

The curious thing is for a particular ID "16" it is returning an Object of Type User_$$_jvst290_G.
For all other IDs it is returning User class.
When i try to access its properties every values is getting fetched perfectly but in eclipse debugger each values are shown as null.

Below is my code

```
boolean success = false;
        Feed feed = this.entityManager.find(Feed.class, feedId);
        User liker = this.entityManager.find(User.class, userId);
        LOGGER.info("unliker is "+liker.getName());
        List<User> likers = feed.getLikers();
        LOGGER.info("likers before unlike:"+likers.size());
        for(User lkr: likers) {
          LOGGER.info("ID:"+lkr.getId());// prints all Ids including 16
        }
        if(likers.remove(liker)) { //Returns false for user with ID 16
            feed.setLikers(likers);
            LOGGER.info("likers afetr unlike:"+feed.getLikers().size());
            this.entityManager.flush();
            success = true;
        }
        else {
            LOGGER.error("User has not liked this product");
            throw new NoRowChangedException("User has not liked this product");
        }
        return success;
```

I'm not sure it may behave same for some other values apart from 16 as well.
Any guesses what is happening? Below is screenshot
[image]

Overridden equal method in User

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        boolean result = false;
        if(obj instanceof User) {
            User user = (User) obj;
            result = this.id == user.id;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: That is called a proxy. It's used by Hibernate to be able to handle lazy XxxtoOne associations. Or when you use EM.getReference().  Everything is normal.

Comment: then why likers.remove(liker) returns false? What should i do to remove Liker with ID 16 from likers list and why it doesn't work same way for other IDs?

Comment: Have you overridden equals() in User (or a superclass of User)? If so, can you post its code?

Comment: added equal method in post. the remove method is working with other matching User object. I am having problem with 16 only

Comment: Is id a primitive type? Is so, you at least need to use equals(), not == (and Hibernate recommends against using the ID for equals, since new entities don't have an ID yet. Not havng n equals method would actually be better. But anyway, what happens if you use `this.getId() == user.getId()` (or `this.getId().equals(user.getId())`)?

Comment: i have not used `getId()` instead of `id`. id is primitive type so `==` should work correctly with primitive type if i'm not wrong. I'll try without equals and will post again

Comment: Right, Removing equal method made it work. but i'm still not sure why its behaving differently for two object under same condition